# creating dynamic grid in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, grid

I'm trying to create a dynamic grid in javascript.

Once I'm able to create the two-dimensional grid I'm going to input variables into my functions so they can accept any numerical inputs. For now, I'm just trying to get the grid the render both vertically and horizontally.

My second function is only allowing me to add cells to the same column instead of appending them horizontally. How can get the new columns to shift horizontally?

Here is my code:

```
  function makeCell() {
  const canvas = document.getElementById('pixelCanvas')

  const newTable = document.createElement('table')
  const tr = document.createElement('tr')
  const td = document.createElement('td')

  canvas.appendChild(newTable);
  newTable.appendChild(tr);
  tr.appendChild(td);
}

function makeLine() {
 let em = '' 
 for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    em += makeCell() 
 }
 return em 
}

function makeGrid() {
 let en = ''
 for (let i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    en += makeLine()
 }
 return en + '\n'
}

makeGrid();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mentally run through the code you'll see where you went wrong in your logic.

MakeGrid fires, you go into the first for loop, makeLine fires, you go into the second inner for loop, makeCell fires, here you select the control with id='pixelCanvas', create a new table, create a new tr and create a new td. Then you append the table to the canvas, the tr to the table and lastly the td to the tr.

That's great for the first cell, but now you want the second... Here's the problem, makeCell completed and we go through round two of the for loop in makeLine. It's the same logic, however, so it creates a new table, but because the id is the same it doesn't overwrite anything. Then, it creates a new tr and a new td and appends those. That's why you end up with just one column, each iteration you're created a new row.

**Solution:**

So how do you fix that? Well, you've probably realized by now you need to create a new row and then iterate through all the cells you want to add to that row BEFORE you append that row to your table.

Modifying your code, this might look like so:

```
function makeCell(tr) {
    // Create new td.
    const td = document.createElement('td');

    // Append td to tr.
    tr.appendChild(td);

    // return tr object with appended td.
    return tr;  
}

function makeLine(newTable) {
    // Create new tr.
    var tr = document.createElement('tr'); 

    // Loop through number of cells.
    for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        // Overwrite tr object with each new cell added.
        tr = makeCell(tr);    
    }

    // Append new tr to table.
    newTable.appendChild(tr);

    // Return the table with the new tr.
    return newTable;
}

function makeGrid() {
    // Select canvas element.
    const canvas = document.getElementById('pixelCanvas');

    // Create new table.
    var newTable = document.createElement('table');

    // Loop through the rows, note use var so that I can pass the
    // newTable object in to our function and overwrite it each loop.
    for (let i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
        // Overwrite with each appended tr.
        newTable = makeLine(newTable)
    }

    // Append completed object to canvas.
    canvas.appendChild(newTable);
}

makeGrid();
```

Note the use of var instead of let, so the object can be overwritten with the new object on each iteration.

Hope that helps!

Comment: thank you! that was super helpful to see how my code was executing!

Comment: No problem! If you feel this solved your issue, please mark as solved.